# cx_oracle execute multiple statements and export data to excel

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

Currently i can use the following code to get a query from excel, run it and export the result to another excel. However, i cant setup a loop to take all the value from "Query" column and run them all, and save the result in the result without overwriting the result of the first query. so i need to use temp1 to take the first value from "Query"

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxxxxxx', service_name='xxxxxx') # if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address special characters such as '\'.
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'xxxxxxx', password='xxxxxx', dsn=dsn_tns)
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('C:\\Python\Excel\sqlinput.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

sql1 = list(excel_data_df['Query'])
temp1=(sql1[1])
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(temp1)
res1 = cur.fetchall()
res1=pd.DataFrame(res1)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Python\Excel\output.xlsx')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your expected output? Do you just need to put in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxxxxxx', service_name='xxxxxx') # if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address special characters such as '\'.
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'xxxxxxx', password='xxxxxx', dsn=dsn_tns)
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('C:\\Python\Excel\sqlinput.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

sql1 = list(excel_data_df['Query'])
i=0 
while i < len(sql1)
    temp1=(sql1[i])
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(temp1)
    res1 = cur.fetchall()
    res1=pd.DataFrame(res1)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Python\Excel\output.xlsx')
    writer.save()
    i += 1
```

Here one example in my case

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas
import xlrd 

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('myuser', 'mypassword', "mydns:myport/myservicename" , encoding= 'UTF-8' )
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('C:\\python\myqueries.xlsx', sheet_name='queries')

print(excel_data_df.columns.ravel())
print(excel_data_df['COLUM_QUERY'].tolist())
print(excel_data_df['ENABLE'].tolist())

sql = excel_data_df['COLUM_QUERY'].tolist()

i = 0
while i < len(sql):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    stmn = (sql[i])
    print(stmn)
    cursor.execute(stmn)
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            break
        print(row)
    i += 1
```

Running my example where the queries are all the same

[image]

Does the following

```
C:\python>python mypython.py
['COLUM_QUERY' 'ENABLE']
['select 1,2 from dual', 'select 1,2 from dual', 'select 1,2 from dual']
[1, 1, 0]
 select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)
 select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)
 select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)
select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)
select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)
select 1,2 from dual
(1, 2)

C:\python>
```

Comment: You should tune `arraysize` and `prefetchrows` for performance, see the cx_Oracle documentation [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html).